# JavaFX-8 Make text caret visible in readonly textarea

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

JavaFX textfields do not show a text caret if you set them to readonly mode. Here is an example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextAreaReadOnly extends Application {

    public TextAreaReadOnly() {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextArea textarea = new TextArea();
        textarea.setText("This is all\nreadonly text\nin here.");
        textarea.setEditable(false);
        Scene scene = new Scene(textarea, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

While it is still possible to select text with Shift+Cursor keys, no caret is displayed. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: Why do you need a `TextCaret` on a `ReadOnly` Text Control? Do you want to style your mouse pointer, when it hovers over the text?

Comment: I don't want the mouse pointer to change. I want the textarea to show the position of TextInputControl.getCaretPosition(). 
I guess the rationale behind the TextArea not showing a caret is that you don't need it since you cannot insert any text anyway, when it is readonly. But this is wrong (IMO), because you can still select text with the cursor keys and for that you absolutely need a caret.

Comment: Maybe allowing editing and overriding edit events to simulate readonly!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggered by [Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27901601/203657), I tried a quick test of my suggestion to extend TextAreaSkin and replace the caretVisible property by one that doesn't check for editability. Seems to work (not thoroughly tested, though) - but requires reflective access of super's private blink property. Obviously dirty and not possible in security restricted contexts ...

```
public static class MyTextAreaSkin extends TextAreaSkin {

    public MyTextAreaSkin(TextArea textInput) {
        super(textInput);
        caretVisible = new BooleanBinding() {
            { bind(textInput.focusedProperty(), textInput.anchorProperty(), 
                    textInput.caretPositionProperty(),
                    textInput.disabledProperty(), displayCaret , blinkProperty() );}
            @Override protected boolean computeValue() {
                return !blinkProperty().get() &&  displayCaret.get() && textInput.isFocused() &&
                        (isWindows() || (textInput.getCaretPosition() == textInput.getAnchor())) 
                        && !textInput.isDisabled(); 
            }
        };
        // rebind opacity to replaced caretVisible property
        caretPath.opacityProperty().bind(new DoubleBinding() {
            { bind(caretVisible); }
            @Override protected double computeValue() {
                return caretVisible.get() ? 1.0 : 0.0;
            }
        });

    }

    BooleanProperty blinkAlias;

    BooleanProperty blinkProperty() {
        if (blinkAlias == null) {
            Class<?> clazz = TextInputControlSkin.class;
            try {
                Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("blink");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                blinkAlias = (BooleanProperty) field.get(this);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException 
                   | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TBD: errorhandling
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return blinkAlias;
    }

}

// usage in a custom TextArea
TextArea textarea = new TextArea() {

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new MyTextAreaSkin(this);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 3):

I want the same thing -- a read-only field, but caret visible for navigation.  I tried:

```
.text-input:readonly { -fx-display-caret: true; }
```

But to no avail.  Digging in to the [FX source code (for 2.2)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextInputControlSkin.java), I found this:

```
caretVisible = new BooleanBinding() {
        { bind(textInput.focusedProperty(), textInput.anchorProperty(), textInput.caretPositionProperty(),
                textInput.disabledProperty(), textInput.editableProperty(), displayCaret, blink);}
        @Override protected boolean computeValue() {
            // RT-10682: On Windows, we show the caret during selection, but on others we hide it
            return !blink.get() && displayCaret.get() && textInput.isFocused() &&
                    (isWindows() || (textInput.getCaretPosition() == textInput.getAnchor())) &&
                    !textInput.isDisabled() &&
                    textInput.isEditable();
        }
    };
```

It looks like there is no way to override the requirement isEditable() at the end of that conditional.  I may paint on a dummy caret as a work-around, which is ugly but I'm not sure there is another way -- looks like you can either fake the caret or fake the read-only aspect (rejecting all edits to the control).

Comment: plus one for digging :-) You might consider implementing a custom skin and override the binding - caretVisible is protected (though blink isn't) and only used in caretPath which is protected also, so you could get away with extending ..

Comment: if you are not in a security restricted environment (and company rules allows): a custom [TextAreaSkin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27904371/203657) seems to do the trick. Not tested for side-effects, though